# Connecting to MongoDb atlas fails when using alpine Docker images

Tags: c#, mongodb, docker, alpine-linux, mongodb-atlas

I've a .net / c# aspnet core application which connects to a MongoDb Atlas Cloud database.
When running localy every thing works fine.

Now i put the application inside a alpine docker image the application the connection fails.
I got some various exceptions pointing out that the authentication doesn't work.

Here my DockerFile which builds and runs the application

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish Api/Api.csproj -o /dockerout/ -c Release

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.3-aspnetcore-runtime-alpine
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80 5000

RUN apk update

COPY --from=builder /dockerout .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research I found an Issue pointing me to the root cause:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9608#issuecomment-401370142

Because it took me a lot of time I'll answer my own question hoping someone is saving the time.

There two possible solutions are 
a) don't use a alpine image 
b) update the openssl package when building the image by adding open ssl like this `apk add --no-cache openssl`

Full DockerFile that solved it for me:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish Api/Api.csproj -o /dockerout/ -c Release

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.3-aspnetcore-runtime-alpine
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80 5000

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache openssl

COPY --from=builder /dockerout .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```